# SCD Type 2 and Insert Error with Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, scd2

I am having trouble inserting records in my data warehouse tables. I have a surrogate key that is created auto increments by 1 for each record. I get the error message:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'TARGET' can only
>   be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Code snippet below:

```
INSERT INTO [DW_Table] (Valid_Start_Date, Valid_End_Date, Current_Flag, Col1, Col2, Col3) 
  SELECT
   Getdate() AS Valid_Start_Date, NULL AS Valid_End_Date, 1 as Current_Flag, Col1, Col2,Col3
  FROM (
    MERGE INTO [DW_Table] AS TARGET
    USING ([Base_Table]) AS SOURCE
    ON ( SOURCEC.Account_Key = TARGET.Account_Key
         AND TARGET.Current_Flag = 1)
    WHEN MATCHED .................................
```

I have tried listing out the fields, as I know the issue lies with trying to insert records to the the auto incrementing field. I have done this as part of the "USING" base table line, but I still get errors.

Can someone please give me some pointers please?

Thanks

Comment: Your Insert columns don't match the Selected columns. the `1 as Current_Flag` is going into the `Col1` into the Insert list.

Comment: IN addition to the issue @WEI_DBA noted, your TARGET table has an IDENTITY column, which is auto generating the value for that column. So you will need to either a) not include that column in your INSERT or b) turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON as the error states. Probably A, but that depends on your situation.

Comment: There's a typo in the query, so I missed out the Current_Flag in the Insert Into. I have amended that now. I don't include the IDENTITY column in the INSERT, but I still get the same error

Comment: Any triggers? What's going on after WHEN MATCHED? Are you able to do this insert without using [MERGE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)? Maybe even just test with only the INSERT to see if the MERGE statement is the problem.

Comment: Following on from WHEN MATCHED, I do a check across my fields to determine if any rows have changed. If they have I set the current_flag to 0, insert a new row and set that to current. The INSERT works fine on it's own. It appears it's a problem with the MERGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists dw_table
drop table if exists dw_table_stg 

create table DW_Table
(
  Id int identity, 
  Valid_Start_Date date, 
  Valid_End_Date date, 
  Current_Flag bit, 
  Account_Key int , 
  constraint uk_account_current unique (Account_Key, Current_Flag),
  Col1 int, 
  Col2 int, 
  Col3 int
)

insert into DW_Table (Account_Key,Col1, Col2, Col3, Current_Flag) 
       values (1,2,3,4,1),(2,2,3,4,1),(3,2,3,4,1)

go


declare @DW_Table_stg table( Account_Key int primary key, Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int)

insert into @DW_Table_stg (Account_Key,Col1, Col2, Col3) values (1,2,5,12)

insert into [DW_Table] 
     ( Account_Key, Valid_Start_Date, Valid_End_Date, Current_Flag, Col1, Col2, Col3) 
select Account_Key, Getdate(),        NULL,           1,            Col1, Col2, Col3
from 
(
    merge into [DW_Table] AS t
    using @DW_Table_stg AS s
    ON ( s.Account_Key = t.Account_Key )
    when matched and t.Current_Flag = 1 and checksum(s.Col1,s.Col2,s.Col3) <> checksum(t.Col1,t.Col2,t.Col3)
         then update set t.Current_flag = 0, t.Valid_End_Date = getdate()
    when not matched 
         then insert  (Valid_Start_Date, Valid_End_Date, Current_Flag,Account_Key,    Col1,   Col2,   Col3) 
         values       (getdate(),        null,           1,           s.Account_Key,s.Col1, s.Col2, s.Col3)
    output $action [ActionType], s.*
) d
where [ActionType] = 'UPDATE'

select *
from DW_Table
order by current_flag desc, Account_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet provided, following are the references your Error Message is trying to make...

TARGET = [DW_TABLE]
COLUMNS = (Valid_Start_Date, Valid_End_Date, Current_Flag, Col1, Col2, Col3)

What it implies is that one of the listed columns in the DW_TABLE is defined as an IDENTITY KEY and hence your INSERT statement should not be specifying a value for it.

Can you share the complete merge query and the column definitions for DW_TABLE ?

Also, the join key says "SOURCEC" instead of "SOURCE". Is that just a typo ?